# WebScraping A Website With Json Content Gives Value Error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape an api call with requests. This is the [website](https://www.nseindia.com/api/event-calendar)

Following Is The Error That It Gives Me:

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Following Is The Code :

```
import requests
import json
import time 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/event-calendar'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'}

request = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
data = json.loads(request.text)
print(data)
```

How Can I Scrape This Website ?

Comment: Link and link in code don't match

Comment: I have edited the question now

Comment: yeah . I already found the api link as shown in the edit.The json Is in different format from the last that's why I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-event-calendar'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'}

request = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text,'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

Answer (score 0):

The table is probably being dynamically generated with Javascript. Therefore, requests won't work. You need selenium and a headless browser to do that.